# Constraints on Type Parameters for object and list of objects

Tags: c#, type-constraints

Is there a way to implement constraint type parameters where T is from a base class or if T is a list containing the "base class"?

Something looking like this :

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T : MyBaseClass, IList<MyBaseClass>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't create generic constraint to work like `OR`.

And just to point that that kind of constraint would have been useless: you would not be able to use neither methods defined in `BaseClass` nor these from `IList` (because `T` could have been the first *or* the second).

Answer (score 1):

No but you could have overloaded methods that take one or the other:

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T : MyBaseClass
{
    public void Process(T instance)
    {
    }

    public void Process(IList<T> list)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you implement an interface on the BaseClass and do.

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T : class, IBaseInterface
```

This also guarantees that the children are implementing the appropriate contracts that you want to expose.